# How do I train wit.ai bot to recognize "take server down"?

Tags: wit.ai

I'm using wit.ai to create a chatbot to which I can ask to perform simple tasks. For example, I created an entity named action and created a keyword named "shutdown" under action. One of the synonym for "shutdown" is "take down". So, if I type

> Could you please **take down 192.168.0.102** for me?

It understands I need to turn off 192.168.0.102 but, how do I train it to recognize **take 192.168.0.102 down** along with **take down 192.168.0.102**?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a wit/on_off entity with a value of "off" (no need to highlight a word, it's a trait entity)

If you're going for predefined devices, create an entity called "device" with a free-text & keywords lookup strategy. The entity should have a keyword list of your devices with a keyword for "server_whatever" (the one you're trying to shut down) and the IP as a synonym.

If you're trying to get any IP and then handle it in the code, create an IP_address entity with a free-text strategy.

Finally train with various examples so that wit can understand whether you want to turn a server on or off and also so that it can learn to recognise IP addresses or devices.